# vscode, and python, the line numbers disappeared

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI3fq.png)

I used to have line numbers (so I should have the addons if needed), but they somehow disappear today (see the screenshot) when I was trying to code. I wonder how I can bring them back?

I tried googling the solution - all suggests I install addons but I do have them - possibly I randomly touched the 'short cut' which makes the line numbers not being displayed.

Comment: thanks, blorgon - that solves my problem!

Comment: then you need to mark that as having answered your question so that this one is closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 10):

On vscode, press Ctrl-Shift-P, and type `user settings`. Click on `Preferences: Open User settings`. in the settings search bar, type in `line numbers`. Then, on the `Editor: Line Numbers: Controls the display of line numbers.`, switch that to on if it isn't already.

Also, make sure the checkbox "Zen Mode" right below it is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: thanks - I guess that is the normal correct answer

Comment: I had to turn them off then back on again.